# Cookie policy notice is not available on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, cookie-policy

Full version of any SE site contains a cookie notice on the bottom of the page:

> [image: full]

But mobile web doesn’t have it anywhere on the screen.

P.S. switching to mobile web is only possible from meta sites due to overlapping a “mobile” link with cookie notice on main sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks fixed now:

> [image: cookie notice on mobile web]